# Placing the_content inside shortcode not working

Tags: php, shortcode, templates

Have placed 
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict plans="silver"]' .$the_content. '[/wcm_restrict]'); ?>`  into a template, but the content isn't appearing.

Have tested 
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict plans="silver"]Big Blue[/wcm_restrict]'); ?>`  so know the tags are working fine.  Also tried `get_the_content`

Content appears also when just using `<?php the_content(); ?>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the variable `$the_content` exists. I'm guessing what you want is the function `the_content()`, but since that actually echoes its output, that won't work either. You need to use the function `get_the_content()` which will return the output (as opposed to echoing it).

Try this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict plans="silver"]' . get_the_content() . '[/wcm_restrict]');
```